# Wrong boolean result in simple expression

Tags: python

I am getting a strange result in this boolean in python. I keep getting the wrong result.

```
string = '94070'
string[0:2] is '95' or string[0:2] is '94'
```

returns False, but when I hardcode in the value '94', it works

```
'94' is '95' or '94' is '94'
```

returns True. I've checked the data types and they are both of type 'str' so I'm not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `==` instead of `is`. In Python, the `is` operator does an object identity check. The `==` operator checks two objects (which may be different objects) to see whether they contain the same contents.

Answer (score 1):

`is` is an *identity* test (is this the exact same object?), not *equality* test. While `is` works coincidentally, as an implementation detail for some things that aren't logically singletons, it shouldn't be used like this; use value equality testing with `==`.

Your test of `'94' is '94'` can work due to a couple of related possibilities:

1. Python often coalesces constant literals in a function (sometimes only on a single line)
2. String literals are often interned by Python, so the same string literal expressed anywhere in the code references a common copy of that string

When you slice off bits of a string, interning isn't involved, so the identity test fails.

Answer (score 0):

Use `is` to see if two arguments refer to the same object and `==` to see if they have the same value.

```
>>> a = 'this is some text.'
>>> b = 'this is some text.'
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
False

>>> a = 'this is some text.'
>>> b = a
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
True
```